# What does it mean to “Always AutoFormat Plain text e-mail documents” in Outlook 2013?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2013

Outlook 2013's AutoFormat tab in the AutoCorrect dialog includes a checkbox to "Always AutoFormat Plain text e-mail documents".  What does this control? A plain text e-mail document includes no formatting information!

Here's the dialog:

[image]

Comment: I would guess it's things like removing extra line breaks, detecting urls and email addresses and other contextual content.

Answer (score 1):

It is a little confusing:

> Always AutoFormat Plain text e-mail documents

means that your plain text *will not be a plain one anymore!*
Outlook will *format it for you*.

In other words:

"*Do not bother about `HTML` or `RTF` tags*, just write your e-mail as a *plain text* and Outlook will do all dirty work with inserting appropriate tags itself".

Answer (score 1):

The following options can be applied to plain text emails, and will be if this option is enabled:

- Replace "straight quotes" with “smart quotes”
- Replace fractions (1/2) with fraction character (½)
- Replace hyphens (--) with dash (—)

Additionally, for the option "Replace *bold* and _italic_ with real formatting", if you use those conventions when composing a plain text email, then the asterisk and underscore characters that you type in those constructs will be stripped from the text. The **bold** and *italic* text will be displayed to you as you compose, but of course they will be lost when the email is actually sent. If you don't have the option to AutoFormat plain text emails enabled, then the asterisks and underscores you type in those constructs will remain in the text when the email is sent.